# Trying to determine if a string is an integer

Tags: java, string, integer

Instructions:
Given a string, determine if it is an integer. For example the 
string “123” is an integer, but the string “hello” is not.

It is an integer if all of the characters in the string are digits.

Return true if it is an integer, or false if it is not.

Hint: There is a method Character.isDigit() that takes a char as an argument 
and returns a boolean value.

What I have so Far:

```
public boolean isInteger(String str) {
    if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)) == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
            break;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm having an issue with returning a boolean value for the string "101" and no string at all (" ")

Comment: `if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)) == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }` this condition is weirdly stated. Why are you evaluating a `boolean` and an `int`?

Comment: Also, you should remove the `break;`, negate that first condition, and put the `return false;` inside it.

Comment: for the "if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)) == 0) { return false; }", I was trying to make the code return false if nothing was put into the string. Also, I tried negating the first condition which made my "101" boolean string correct, but it ended up making all the other return values incorrect.

Comment: possible duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java

Answer (score 8):

You could use a regular expression.

```
return str.matches("\\d+");
```

won't work for negative numbers, though.

You could also use `Integer.parseInt` and catch the `NumberFormatException` and return true/false accordingly.

Or, you should not break the first digit you find, as you need to check *all characters*, only until you find one that *is not* a digit. Again, this does not capture negative numbers

```
public boolean isInteger(String str) {
    if(str == null || str.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Personally, option 2 is the best, but your instructions seem to imply that you need to iterate over character values

Answer (score 3):

Just check if Integer.parseInt throws exception or not.

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt(string);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: The program I'm using is a very limited compiler with the purpose of teaching people how to do particular methods of Java in each chapter. It (sadly) cannot use the .parseInt because the current lesson does not teach it.

Answer (score 2):

You are close, but have mixed up logic. I'll go through it with you now.

```
if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)) == 0) {
    return false;
}
```

<strike>I'm not sure what this above statement if trying to test. I see that you are checking if the `0` index is a digit, but then you compare it to `0`. Even if this was written correctly, this statement can be removed because you are about to iterate through the string.</strike> After reading your comment it seems that it was meant to check for `null` or empty string. In which case you may want to test the `string` directly.

```
if(str == null || str.isEmpty())
    return false;
```

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
        break;
    }
     else {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

The above `break;` does not do what I think you think it does. `break;` will exit out of the `for` loop, thus only checking the first `character`. I suggest rewriting this `if-else` to get rid of the `else` and negate your `isDigit` method. See my code below.

```
for(int i = 0;i < str.length();i++){
    if(!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))
        return false;
}
return true;
```

You only want to `return false` if the `character` is not a digit.

Comment: in the checking logic, should handle hyphen - for negative value (and plus + for positive one)

Comment: @kidnan1991 I don't believe OP is worried about `+` or `-`. Since OP was pointed in the direction of `Character.isDigit()`, `+` and `-` are not digits and therefore will `return false` if input

Comment: I got your point. OP does not care about the sign (- or +0).
About your solution, it it not correct if the prefix is empty (OP want it to be false). So, firstly, trimmed the string => Check size before any process

Comment: @kidnan1991 I considered trimming the string, but I don't think this will matter. I could add another part to the first `if` statement, but if the `string` only has a space in it, then it is not a digit and will exit anyways.

Answer (score 2):

All the above solution seems correct to me but I would like to give one more solution to this problem. You can check this using ASCII values too:

```
private Boolean IsInteger(String str)
{
   int length = str.length(),c=0;
   if(length==0)
      return false;
   for(int i=0;i<length; i++)
   {
      c = (int)str.charAt(i)-48;
      if(!(c>=0 && c<10))
         return false;
   }
  return true;
}
```

I think My solution is much better because it used less number of library functions per iterations.

I am not checking for negative values because in the questions you have specified that the string is Integer if all the characters are digits. If you want to check negative numbers you can do it by adding one condition in i==0;.

Comment: Vote for handling empty string as OP want

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using regex to identify integer.

Like this

```
public boolean isInteger(String str){
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
  boolean b = m.matches();
  return b;
}
```

Comment: So... just `str.matches("[0-9]+");`?

Comment: Haha, yes, it's same.  I just copy from the java API example

Answer (score 0):

In java, you can use this regex pattern : 
It will filter either negative or positive value

```
private static final String NUMBER_REGEX = "(^\\d++)|(^[\\-]{1}\\d++)";
private static final Pattern NUMBER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(NUMBER_REGEX);
final Matcher matcher = NUMBER_PATTERN.matcher(inputString);
if(matcher.find()) {
// If matcher => parse the value
final String sNumber = matcher.group();
final int value = Integer.parseInt(sNumber);
} else {
// Not matching
}
```